# How to solve an equation involving gamma and incomplete gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

How can I solve for $t$ in $$S = 1 - \gamma(\alpha/p,(\lambda t)^p) / \Gamma (\alpha / p)$$
where $$ \gamma(s,x)=\int_0^x t^{s-1}e^{-t} dt$$

$S$ is the survival function for a generalized gamma distribution. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Search “Inverse Gamma Regularized” in WolframAlpha

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the upper incomplete Gamma function as
$$\Gamma(a,z)=\int_z^\infty t^{a-1}\mathrm e^{-t}\mathrm dt \\ =\Gamma(a)-\gamma(a,z)$$
Hence
$$S=1-\frac{\Gamma(a/p)-\Gamma\big(a/p,(\lambda t)^p\big)}{\Gamma(a/p)}$$
Define the regularized incomplete Gamma function,
$$Q(a,z)=\frac{\Gamma(a,z)}{\Gamma(a)}$$
So
$$S=Q\big(a/p,(\lambda t)^p\big)$$
Define the inverse w.r.t $z$,
$$Q^{-1}(a,s)~~\text{is the solution for }z~\text{in} \\ s=Q(a,z)$$
Therefore
$$Q^{-1}(a/p,S)=(\lambda t)^p \\ \frac{\big(Q^{-1}(a/p,S)\big)^{1/p}}{\lambda}=t$$
$Q^{-1}$ is implemented in the Wolfram Language as `InverseGammaRegularized`.